# Python unittest async doesn't display print

Tags: python, unit-testing, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I want to use Python's async unittest and followed the instructions from [here](https://bbc.github.io/cloudfit-public-docs/asyncio/testing.html). I tried the examples from the source and they all worked except for not displaying the `print` as demonstrated. **How do you display `print` using Python's async unittest?**

```
import asyncio
import unittest
    
async def my_func():
    print("my_func", flush=True)
    
class TestStuff(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_my_func(self):
        _ = await my_func()
```

Comment: I did a quick test and it works for me. I run it like this: `python -m unittest test.py` and used your exact code (python 3.10.10 btw)

Comment: I found out it was probably because I named the file UnitTest.py. I did a change to test.py and it now works!